# Гистограмма для массива с числами

Tags: java, массивы

Дан массив: mas={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 24, 55, 62, 73, 74, 89, 93, 94, 95};
Нужно вывести гистограмму, где каждая колонка отображает количество чисел в каждом диапазоне (от 0-9, 10-19, 20-29 ... 90-99):

```
# # #  # # # # #
#   #      #   #
#              #
# 
#
```

Создал массив, не могу правильно составить цикл. Прошу о помощи или о совете как граммотно подойти к этому вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int[] mas = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 24, 55, 62, 73, 74, 89, 93, 94, 95};

    int[] gist = new int[10]; // Инициализация идет нулями
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        int vol = mas[i] / 10;
        gist[vol]++;
    }
    boolean stat = true;
    while (stat) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < gist.length; i++) {
            if (gist[i] > 0) {
                System.out.print("#");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            gist[i]--;
            if (gist[i] <= 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (count > 9) {
            stat = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку. Дальше мне осталось вывести символы в столбец через этот массив, правильно ?

Comment: Поправил код, сделал вывод в консоль.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А что делает 4 строка gist[vol] ? попытался вывести sout(gist[vol]), показывает 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 .

Comment: gist[vol] - эта запись означает обращение к элементу под номером vol массива gist. Запись gist[vol]++ означает, что этот элемент массива увеличивается на 1. Таким образом мы считаем сколько чисел есть в каждом диапазоне.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
PrintWriter pw;
Scanner sc;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    new Main().run();
    }
    public void run() throws IOException{
    sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    //new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=sc.nextInt();
    byte [] mas = new byte[i];
    i=0;
    //получаем массив mas
    while(i<mas.length){
        mas[i]=sc.nextByte();i++;
    }
    //получаем количество чисел в диапазоне (0-9, ..., 90-99)
    int[] gist=new int[10];
    for(i=0;i<gist.length;i++){
        gist[i]=getD(mas,10*i,10*i+9);
    }
    //получаем максимальную высоту колонок
    int max=getMax(gist);
    //создаём массив String для вывода
    //гистаграммы построчно
    String[] sg=new String[max];
    //Для каждой строки определяем существование
    //столбца (>0) и если существует
    //то прибавляем к строке "#" решётка, а потом
    //вычитаем столбец
    //иначе если столбец нулевой, то к строке прибавляем " " пробел
    for(i=0;i<sg.length;i++){
        sg[i]="";
        for(int j=0;j<gist.length;j++){
        if(gist[j]>0){
        sg[i]+="#";gist[j]--;
        } else if(gist[j]==0)sg[i]+=" ";
        }
    }
    //выводим гистограмму в файл
    pw = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
    //new PrintWriter(System.out);
    for(i=0;i<sg.length;i++){
        pw.println(sg[i]);
    }
    pw.close();
    }
    //[min,max]
    public int getD(byte[] mas,
                    int min,
                    int max){
    int d=0;
    for(int i=0;i<mas.length;i++){
        if((min<=mas[i])&&(mas[i]<=max))d++;
    }
    return d;
    }
    public int getMax(int[] gist){
    int max=0;
    for(int i=0;i<gist.length;i++){
        if(gist[i]>max)max=gist[i];
    }
    return max;
    }
}
```

В input.txt вводить сначала длинну массива, а потом сам массив.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но в Вашем коде мой компилятор netBeans выдает ошибки, не могли бы вы проверить пожалуйста.

Comment: @Oleg Khegay исправлено. Если неизвестна длина массива, то лучше использовать ArrayList и ждать ошибку io.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] arr = {5, 15, 4, 16, 25, 17};

    ArrayList n10 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList n20 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList n30 = new ArrayList();

    for(Integer x: arr){
        if(x<9){
            n10.add(x);
        }
        else if(x>9 && x<=19){
            n20.add(x);
        }
        else if(x>19 && x<=29){
            n30.add(x);
        }
    }


    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        if(x <= (n10.size()-1)){
            System.out.print(n10.get(x) + " ");
        }else{
            System.out.print("* ");
        }

        if(x <= (n20.size()-1)){
            System.out.print(n20.get(x) + " ");
        }else{
            System.out.print("* ");
        }

        if(x <= (n30.size()-1)){
            System.out.print(n30.get(x) + " ");
        }else{
            System.out.print("* ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    }
```

[image]

Найти элементы нужного диапазона несложно.
Но вот все это вывести виде гистограммы - уже веселей. 
P.S Всю эту лапшу можно по методам разложить.